# Component props unreachable with react-redux

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-redux

**Context**: Simple React Native app leverages Redux to manage the complexity.

**Versions**:

- typescript v3.0.3
- react-native v0.56.0
- redux v4.0.0
- @types/react-redux v6.0.9
- @types/redux v3.6.0

**Problem**: My JSX main component does not see properties (the errors included in comments).

The first file:

```
//app.tsx
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainRedux ownProp="as"/> //[1]: Type '{ ownProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<AllProps>'. Property 'appPermissions' is missing in type '{ ownProp: string; }'.
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

and the second file:

```
//MainRedux.tsx
export interface ApplicationState { //originally in another file
  appPermissions: AppPermissionsState;
  //...
}

type StateProps = ApplicationState; //alias appPermissions is in the Application State

interface DispatchProps {
  getPermissions: typeof getPermissions;
  //...
}

interface OwnProps {
  ownProp: string;
}

type AllProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps;

export class MainRedux extends React.Component<AllProps> {
  constructor(props: AllProps) {
    super(props);
    props.getPermissions(); //[2]: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'props.getPermissions()')
  }
  //...
} //class

//...
const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<
  StateProps,
  OwnProps,
  ApplicationState
> = (state: ApplicationState, ownProps: OwnProps): StateProps => {
  return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsFunction<
  DispatchProps,
  OwnProps
> = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, ownProps: OwnProps): DispatchProps => ({
  getPermissions: bindActionCreators(getPermissions, dispatch)
  //...
});

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, ApplicationState>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MainRedux);
```

while, [1] is the compile time error and [2] is the runtime one.

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I put some debug info into `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, but it seems `connect` does not call them. I can go further and suppose that even `connect` is not being invoked.

Comment: Add in a method within your MainRedux class: `componentDidMount () {console.log(this.props)}` Can you see any props in there? The first error is a TypeScript error.

Comment: @JRK, [1] yep, that's the TS error. I followed your suggestion. `this.props` is empty (`{}`).

Comment: @JRK, after a while I have `{"ownProp":"as"}` inside `this.props`. Don't ask me how it happened, because I don't know :/ The rest of necessary properties still missing.

Comment: Do you have the complete code on github? Quite hard to figure out without testing it.

Comment: @JRK, Nope not yet. Too early to put it there.

Comment: For me it looks like there is no initial states from reducers which seems not run, but they do.

Comment: How are you importing `MainRedux` in `app.tsx`?  The error would make sense if you are doing `import { MainRedux } from "MainRedux.tsx"` (i.e., the named export of the original class that hasn't been wrapped by Redux).  In that case, you should change the import to `import MainRedux from "MainRedux.tsx"` (i.e., the default export of the wrapped component returned by `connect`).

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, you saved me a lot of time. It was that. I posted the answer thanks to your remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MattMcCutchen 's comment hit me. After all, the `connect` function returns a decorated class which is no longer the same component class, e.g. `MyComponent` but totally different one, e.g. `let ConnectedMyCommponent = connect(...)` which one can be imported then as `import {ConnectedMyComponent} from '.\...'` into the file with the parent `Provider` tag, e.g. `<Provider><ConnectedMyComponent></Provider>.`

My mistake was that when I was refactoring the code I did not change the way of importing from `import {MainRedux} from './...'` to `import MainRedux from './...'`.

I would give a simple tip for everyone who moves from vanilla react-native into redux react-native: dispose of every `export` keyword at your defined component class, becasue `connect` creates a new class for you. Otherwise, you spend a lot of time trying to understand frequently incomprehensible error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mapping for the state to props

As a test you can put this in your MapStateToProps function:

```
const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<StateProps,OwnProps,ApplicationState> = 
(state: ApplicationState, ownProps: OwnProps): StateProps => {
  return {test : "hello"}
};
```

and see if you see `test` in your `console.log(this.props)` in your `componentDidMount()`

If so, you'll need to map your object so:

```
return {
 propkey1 : state.propkey1,
 propkey2 : state.propkey2
 .... etc
}
```

It's quite hard to determine without the codebase though.

Comment: It's only a syntax. I tried even that. It was not better.

Comment: Building it now

Comment: I've made it. Nothing changes. Please, read my update in the question post.

Comment: Without seeing the whole codebase it's hard to determine. Why don't you strip it back to the bare basics and see if that works?